# Using date in CreateQueryDef

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I have a table on which I run a query that I export to Excel.

Here is an example:

**Table: Food**

```
  Item   | Price | Limit_Date |
-------------------------------
Carrot   | 0.80  | 08/07/2015 |
Salmon   | 4.30  | 01/07/2015 |
Biscuits | 2.40  | 15/12/2015 |
Milk     | 1.00  | 25/06/2015 |
```

And I run this code in vba:

**Code**

```
Dim cdb as DAO.Database
Dim qdf as DAO.QueryDef

Set cdb = CurrentDb

Const xlsxPath = "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Foo.xlsx"

Set qdf=cdb.CreateQueryDef("Omnomnomnom", _
       "SELECT Item, Price FROM Food WHERE Limit_Date >= [pDate];")
Set qdf=Nothing

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel112Xml, "Omnomnomnom", xlsxPath, True
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Omnomnomnom"
```

It works well as it is, but I want to replace the parameter `[pDate]` with a hardcoded date so access doesn't ask for it anymore.

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

- Using `#01/07/2015#`
- Using `DateValue("1 July 2015")` with and without `#` around
- Using `Format("01/07/2015", "dd/mm/yyyy")` with and without `#` around

For each of these cases the query returns everything in the table, like it doesn't take it into account the date. I already checked that my Limit_Date field is Date/Time in my table. And no errors are popping.

The query only works if I keep `[pDate]` and I manually enter `01/07/2015` when access prompts me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in Access needs to be surrounded by the `#` tags so that it recognizes the date you have passed. The other important factor to consider is that JET requires the date format to be `mm/dd/yyyy` as opposed to the normal `dd/mm/yyyy`. So your problem is because you are using `#` but the wrong format or the right format with no `#`. So try using something like,

```
Dim cdb as DAO.Database
Dim qdf as DAO.QueryDef

Set cdb = CurrentDb

Const xlsxPath = "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Foo.xlsx"

Set qdf=cdb.CreateQueryDef("Omnomnomnom", _
       "SELECT Item, Price FROM Food WHERE Limit_Date >= #07/01/2015#;")
Set qdf=Nothing

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel112Xml, "Omnomnomnom", xlsxPath, True
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Omnomnomnom"
```

There is some interesting article with [International Date Formats in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html), by Allen Browne. Hope this helps !

Comment: It works now, but can you explain me why Access executes my query without any problem as I manually enter 01/07/2015 when it asks for pdate ? Isn't the problem basically the same ?

Comment: No, because when you are using the a Parameter, the DB engine, maps the data type to the parameter passed. When you are hardcoding date values, the compiler does not know what is the data type till the point of execution. That is the reason the specifiers `#` instructs it is a Date type, a`'` for String type and anything else is Number type. When using a `#` it constructs the data in American format, which is done automatically when using the Query builder or Parameters. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the date as a string expression to be concatenated with the SQL:

```
Dim sDate As String

sDate = Format(pDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

Set qdf=cdb.CreateQueryDef("Omnomnomnom", _
    "SELECT Item, Price FROM Food WHERE Limit_Date >= # & sDate & "#;")
```